# .htaccess seo friendly url not found issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I am trying to create SEO Friendly URL using htaccess php.

Here is the original URL :

http://www.example.in/viewitem.php?typedp=bus&viewdp=bus-seat-test-item

expected SEO Friendly URL :

http://www.example.in/bus/bus-seat-test-item

Using the following rule in .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule typedp/(.*)/viewdp/(.*)/ viewitem.php?typedp=$1&viewdp=$2
```

But it shows as not found 404 error.

I am new to this concept.

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /viewitem.php?typedp=$1&viewdp=$2 [QSA, L]
```

take a look at : [Mod Rewrite Generator](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php)

Comment: Sounds and fast answer. You might want to add a `QSA` flag, you never know... And maybe replace the `L` flag by an `END` flag.

Comment: @arkascha :I think replacing `L` by `END` is not required in this situation. am I right?

Comment: I cannot say, since I do not know the situation, do I? Certainly it would be safer, woudn't it? Unless the OP is using a really outdated http server.

Comment: I think we're both correct. Actually using `L` or `END` depends on situation :)